# C# double quote argument

Tags: c#

In the app.config file, I have:

```
add key="DataFileLocation" value="E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"/>
```

In the code I have:

```
Process P2 = new Process();
P2.StartInfo.FileName = "restore.bat";
P2.StartInfo.Arguments = + "\"" + DataFileLocation.ToString() + "\"";
P2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
P2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
P2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
P2.Start();
```

The output to 'restore.bat' is:

```
-v dataloc=\"E:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\\"
```

As you can see, there's an extra "\" at the beginning which is breaking the bat/sql statement...

Andrew

Comment: That extra \ is either already in the string or is coming from somewhere else in the line of code that you've posted part of.

Comment: Can you show the full code?

Comment: I dont see the problem here! You add the "\" and the slash appears....

Comment: Have you tried using `string.format("\"{0}\"", ...)` instead? Also, @JP-t, the "\" is an escape, therefore applies the `"` verbatim in this context.

Comment: Why not use @''whatever you need''

Comment: You might want to take a look at Path: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I've edited the question with better details.

Comment: What can you see with the debugger? Contents of DataFileLocation and the concatenation. Is this really the exact code, you don't have things like `'\"'` (single quotes) or `@"\""`?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems like you are already adding a extra `\`, so is the output according to your logic.

The best way to combine path is that you should use the [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method provided by static `Path` class, it takes care of all the extra `\`

Try this

```
var finalPath = Path.Combine(DataFileLocation.ToString(), "what_ever_path_you_want_to_combine");
```